# How can i get the hours from ngx moment pipe?

Tags: angular, angular-moment

I am having this prop

```
date = '2021-11-16T23:00Z';
```

when i apply pipes on string date

```
{{dat | amUtc | amLocal | amDateFormat:'L' }}
```

i get in my HTML

```
11/16/2021
```

But i can't find a way where i will include the hours

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-moment
```

So at the end i will have 11/16/2021 23:00

If it is AM for example `'2021-11-16T08:00Z'`
then i need to get `1/16/2021 08:00`

Comment: Please post a minimally reproducible example and not just code fragments.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular have pipe for dates, and i think will solve your problem.

Take a look on angular doc DatePipe:
https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

If i undestood well, you will do like this:

Component:

```
date = '2021-11-16T23:00Z';
```

HTML:

```
{{date | date:'m/DD/yyyy hh:mm'}}
```

The result will be:

```
1/16/2021 08:00
```